# Combine two bytes (one positive and another negative ) into short in java

Tags: java, c++, byte, short

I am trying to port my C++ project in java. 
Down the line I have to read some bytes from serial port and combine two bytes into short. Things are working elegantly with below code.

```
               ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
                bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

                bb.put(b1);
                bb.put(b2);
                  result = bb.getShort(0);
```

In c++ project instead of short they have unsigned short (in java we don't have unsigned).

```
So my above logic result does not align with C++ result for below case:-
 b1 = 106 ,  b2 = -1     c++ result = 150   and java = -150


 b1 =-6, b2 =   -1     506 in VC++ but -6 in java

However, if only first byte is negative then my result are similar :
b1 = -12 ,  b2 = 1     c++ result = 500   and java = 500
```

I want to align my result with c++. any suggestions and help would be highly appreciable .

Comment: What exactly do you want ? Your C++ is clearly NOT combining two bytes, but the java is doing so correctly. We can't tell how to do the java if we don't know the C++ logic.

Comment: @ElderBug in c++ they are combining two bytes into unsigned short but in java short is signed  ...is that the reason for this discrepancy in result ?

Comment: The C++ is NOT combining two bytes into unsigned short. At least not in the obvious way. There is some logic that you didn't show.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `getShort()`, use `getInt()` instead.

Your problem is that the most significant bit is being interpreted as the sign bit due to the fact that this is the case for a signed short. If you extend the data type so that bit is no longer considered the sign bit, you should get the behaviour you want.

You may need to pad out your buffer to do this:

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

bb.put(b1);
bb.put(b2);
bb.put(0);
bb.put(0);

result = bb.getInt(0);
```

**EDIT:** This *would* work if only the C++ code was doing the right thing, but as pointed out in the comments above, it isn't (i.e. it is NOT simply taking the two bytes and combining them into a short. It performs some other transform on them as well).

Comment: its giving  65131 for {107,-2}..expected is 661

Comment: I'm not getting this exception. Are you sure you're using the code *exactly* as above (including the parameter `0` to `getInt`?)

Comment: removed that comment .but not getting expected result.

Comment: As per above edit, you need to post the actual logic performed by the C++ code. The above code really is taking the input and combining the bytes into an unsigned short. The C++ code isn't doing that.

Answer (score 0):

java -6 (0xFFFA) is correct, C++ 506 (0x01FA) is not. 0xFA. Seems you mistyped -1: 1 or - -1.